# Canvas ImageData don't get more than 102,000 values?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am getting pixels values from an image using canvas. The image size is 170*170 pixels. Here is my code:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.style.width = img.width;
canvas.style.height = img.height;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height).data;
```

It works well, I have values in pixelData, until I reach pixelData[102000]... I've test it with a white image, and all the values from pixelData[0] to pixelData[101999] are 255, but then it is 0 until the end...

Somebody sees why? Maybe this is about canvas width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your canvas size is not what you think it is.

You are only setting the size of  the canvas *element* not the canvas bitmap:

```
canvas.style.width = img.width;
canvas.style.height = img.height;
```

This means your bitmap is actually 300 x 150 pixels in size, the default size, and you're just scaling that to the size of the image (since it's all white you won't be able to detect this so easily).

Since your image is 170 x 170 pixels you will only paint part of the canvas leaving the rest to default RGBA value [0,0,0,0].

In order to properly set the size of the canvas you must edit the above mentioned lines to be:

```
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
```